# Vb Can You Run Another Program Inside the one you are making.

Tags: vb.net

Hello All I was Wondering if it was possible to run another program in a window inside you're vb program? So here is what I was thinking I want to make a window with like three buttons at the top. Stop, >, >> The too arrows would be the speed. Then I want another window below this to run a program called NCO view which is a Cnc simulator. Is This even Possible? If so can I know where to start and where to find information on this.

Comment: It's possible...but kinda of cludgy.  Dependson the app you're "hosting".  Use Process.Start() to run the external EXE, then the SetParent() API to move that app into your own.  You might need to reposition that window afters with the SetWindowPos() API.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous and can't figure out what you're expecting really but YES this is totally possible in vb.net.
If you've got several process simultaneously, you can launch them on different threads. ([Parallel programming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71285/Introducing-NET-4-0-Parallel-Programming))

And if you need several forms you can proceed by using Modal form: follow [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Can Vb.net be programed in Visual Studio Express

Comment: Yes I think so, with the Microsoft Visual Studio Express **for Windows** edition